# Ember, Visual Studio, and WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, ember.js, ember-cli

I primarily use Visual Studio, C#, and WebApi for my projects.  We're looking to utilizing Ember, Ember relies heavily on Node Package Manager.  Which Visual Studio does support, but is there a way to integrate Ember and their Command Line better into Visual Studio?

Currently, we would use Node and Ember for our frontend, then we would open Visual Studio and our backend code.  They're currently separated, was hoping to avoid having to switch a better integration.

Comment: I have used `Visual Studio Code` and the Microsoft devs Ive met at meetups are keep on making it play nice with Ember.js.  So keep an eye on that as theyre releasing builds quickly.

Comment: For official Visual Studio, not Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Yes, I was suggesting to also consider looking at `VS Code` since their team is working at making it play nice with Ember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also tried myself and at the current time there are no usable plugins that help integrate ember into VS.  You may use VS editor to modify the source but you wont get a lot of the build tools and extra features of VS.

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same scenario, WebApi backend + Ember client. Currently I add de ember app folder in the visual studio solution as "Existing Web Site", hide node_modules and temp windows folders and run all commands from external command line.